# WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a running `hybrid app` on my machine. when I moved to another machine through flash drive and after opening in editor. I run this command `ionic serve` i got this error \;

> WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please
>   rename it.                                            Uh oh! Looks
>   like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
>   Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
>   Do you need to run `npm install`?

Comment: what is your ionic version? cmd "ionic -v"

Comment: @ErenAkkus it is 2.1.4

Comment: and the other machine ?

Comment: i don't know, may I find this from code?

Comment: @ErenAkkus possibly it was in ionic framework 1

Comment: I guessed. i answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inonic version 2 and higher want to rename the file named "ionic.project" to "ionic.config.json".

i think your first machine ionic version < 2.0.0, the other one >= 2.0.0

my advice; rename the file name "ionic.project" to "ionic.config.json". And update ionic at your first machine.

```
$ ionic lib update
```